# DataTable copying selected rows and columns to another DataTable by index

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, datatable

I have two DataTable's

- ImportExcelDT
- ExportExcelDT

Out of these two, one of the table contains some data, I am checking each row as validation and deleting the invalid columns from the table and adding it to the second table.

Here's the code, which I'm using

```
            int Col = 0;
            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(ImportExcelDT);

                if (ImportExcelDT.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ImportExcelDT.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {

                        string EmpCod = ImportExcelDT.Rows[i]["Employee Code"].ToString();
                        bool isEmpCod = Regex.IsMatch(EmpCod, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9/-]+$");

                       //Here i am checking condition if its false
                       if (!isEmpCod)
                        {
                            count++;
                          //Now i want to copy and delete selected row in another data table 
                            for (int j = 0; j < ImportExcelDT.Rows.Count; j++)
                            {
                                ImportExcelDT.Rows[j][i] = ExportExcelDT.Rows[j][Col];
                                ImportExcelDT.Rows[i].Delete();

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
```

I'm bit confused on which row & column should i select on `ImportExcelDT.Rows[j][i]` and `ExportExcelDT.Rows[j][Col];` while deleting and adding it.

Comment: is this on `mportExcelDT.Rows[j][i] = ExportExcelDT.Rows[j][Col];` correct? what do you want to do?

Comment: if i got validation error on row 7 then i want to copy column 7 to new data table and delete column 7 from old datatable

Comment: so it should be `ExportExcelDT.Rows[j][Col]=ImportExcelDT.Rows[j][i];` right?

Comment: There is no row at position 1.
or 
There is no row at position 0
i am getting that error

Comment: Where you are using count++ and col?

Comment: count is nothing i was just counting validation errors and col i think for columns changing change u suggest me any thing its not working
i just want to copy selected row to new datatable and delete from old one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124787/discussion-between-balaji-and-shaikh-aamir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
if (ImportExcelDT.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    ExportExcelDT = ImportExcelDT.Clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < ImportExcelDT.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string EmpCod = ImportExcelDT.Rows[i]["Employee Code"].ToString();
        bool isEmpCod = Regex.IsMatch(EmpCod, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9/-]+$");
        //Here i am checking condition if its false
            if (!isEmpCod)
            {
                count++;
                //Now i want to copy and delete selected row in another data table 
                ExportExcelDT.ImportRow(ImportExcelDT.Rows[i]);
                ImportExcelDT.Rows[i].Delete();
            }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it will go through each row, after everything completes, it gets out of the loop

Comment: shall i use break;??

Comment: I'm not getting your requirements, what you want to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124792/discussion-between-shaikh-aamir-and-balaji).